How to use (Rolling/Sliding) Window Linear Regression to Predict Future Data
I am trying to implement a sliding window regression to predict stock prices and I realized I didn't understand how sliding window regression works for prediction. I have some training data (the company's closing stock prices for days 0-149) and testing data (closing price of days 150-169).
I used a window of size 15 on the training data and so I have predictions for days 15-149.
The prediction for day $i$ is $f_i(i)$ where $f_i$ is the linear regression line from the stock prices for days $[i-15,i)$ (where $0 \leq i < 15$). But how exactly do I use this to predict future stock prices for days 150-169? I want to compare this to the testing data which I should not use in my model.
This is a conceptual question. Not a question about implementation.

I am working on exact same problem.
You should fit a polynomial of nth degree to your data and then give the input as x to get predicted value of y in that fitted polynomial.
The polynomial fitted should be on the Window points only. Keep it sliding

What you're saying is a bit vague. Which points exactly do I use to construct my polynomial? What is $n$?
